# load images with jquery-ajax after page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load 100 images (110x110 px) from my data base.

So first, I called the bellow code at the end of my html file :

```
var images = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getImages.php",
        data: {artist: users[i]},
        success: function(res) {
            images += '<li><img src="' + res + '" /></li>';
        },
        async: false
    });
}

$("#list").append(images); // add images to my page (#list is an ul element)

$( document ).ready(function() {
    displayWithEffect(); // shows all images
});
```

The problem is it takes too long to load 100 images (about 6s), and my web browser doesn't display anything before that.

So, I changed my code to load all contents first and then change `img` sources (`src`). So I did this :

```
var images = "";
for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
     images += '<li><img src="" /></li>';
}

$("#list").append(images); // add images to my page

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $("#list li").each(function(idx, li) {
        var product = $(li);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getImages.php",
            data: {artist: users[i]},
            success: function(ret) {
                $(li).children(":first").attr("src", ret);
            },
            async: false
        });
        i++;
    });
    displayWithEffect(); // shows all images
});
```

But I still get the same effect as before.

How can I completely load and display all contents of my page except my 100 images first, and then load these images (behind some `loading.gif` animation) with ajax ?

Comment: What is `res` variable at the third line of the second code?

Comment: edited... copy/paste error

Comment: What about using an existing library for that, something like this [the Lazy Load plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$(document).ready(function() { ...` with `$(window).on('load', function() { ...`

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var images = "";
    for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
        images += '<li><img src="' + res + '" /></li>';
    }

    $("#list").append(images); // add images to my page

    $("#list li").each(function(idx, li) {
        var product = $(li);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getImages.php",
            data: {artist: users[idx]},
            success: function(ret) {
                product.children(":first").prop("src", ret);
            }
        });
    });
    displayWithEffect(); // shows all images
});
```

Comment: And you did it like this, removed the async:false etc ?

Comment: `async: false` was actually the problem. Thank you!

Comment: It would be, it completely locks the browser, and you should never ever, ever, ever, ever, ever, ever use it.